Vercel Deployment Issues with Contentful on Nextjs14
Cannot connect to contentful in vercel deployment despite uploading .env file, connecting locally, and connecting to gmail via nodemailer locally and prod while storing credentials in same .env

Locally I'm able to connect to contentful (though had to manually delete my cache)
Uploaded the .env.local file into vercel
Connects to gmail through nodemailer via env values
Will not connect to contentful on prod
Only have one contentful environment (master), so not an issue of master vs staging

const contentfulEndpoint = process.env.CONTENTFUL_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT

    const getPhotoGallery = async () => {
        const requestBody = JSON.stringify({query: photoAlbumQuery})

        if (contentfulEndpoint) {
            const fetchOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.CONTENTFUL_DELIVERY_TOKEN}`
                },
                body: requestBody
            }


